# How to make one capturing group of regular expression on bigquery?

Tags: sql, regex, google-bigquery

I am getting the following error: Regular expressions passed into extraction functions must not have more than 1 capturing group.

And this is what I am trying to extract : `regexp_substr(UPPER(tags), r'(TG\d{6})|(BD\d{6})')`
Does anyone know how can I change this to one capturing group?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either of below instead

```
regexp_substr(UPPER(tags), r'(TG\d{6}|BD\d{6})')
```

or

```
regexp_substr(UPPER(tags), r'(?:TG|BD)\d{6}')
```